# Transaction handling in dataset based insert/update

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

I am trying to insert bulk records in a sql server database table using dataset. But i am unable to do transaction handling. Please help me to apply transaction handling in below code.

I am using `adapter.UpdateCommand.Transaction = trans;` but this line give me an error of Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

**Code:**

```
    string ConnectionString = "server=localhost\\sqlexpress;database=WindowsApp;Integrated Security=SSPI;";
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
            conn.Open();
            SqlTransaction trans = conn.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.Serializable);
            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Test ORDER BY Id", conn);

            SqlCommandBuilder builder = new SqlCommandBuilder(adapter);
            adapter.UpdateCommand.Transaction = trans;

            // Create a dataset object
            DataSet ds = new DataSet("TestSet");
            adapter.Fill(ds, "Test");

            // Create a data table object and add a new row
            DataTable TestTable = ds.Tables["Test"];

            for (int i=1;i<=50;i++)
            {
                DataRow row = TestTable.NewRow();

                row["Id"] = i;

                TestTable .Rows.Add(row);
            }

            // Update data adapter
            adapter.Update(ds, "Test");

            trans.Commit();

            conn.Close();
```

Comment: is `adapter.UpdateCommand` perhaps `null` here?

Answer (score 1):

If the data-adapter doesn't make it easy to pass in a transaction, and doesn't handle it internally, then you *might* be able to force it by using `TransactionScope` instead - since this is ambient rather than explicit.

However! My main guidance here would be more simple: *stop using data-sets and data-adapters*. They were *essentially* hangover from pre-.NET patterns, and were handy when the data tooling for .NET was in an early state. It is no longer in that state. Virtually *any other* data access tool would be preferable.

Answer (score 0):

I could not test your code, but I think you should also pass the connection of the `trans` object to your adapter like in the following example:

```
...
adapter.UpdateCommand.Connection = trans.Connection;
adapter.UpdateCommand.Transaction = trans;
...
```

Good luck!

Source: [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17680/Using-TableAdapters-with-transactions)

Comment: Oh, indeed, how would it be possible to update a SELECT SQL statement?  :)

Comment: @lhsan well, the adapter can infer a lot of that from a select statement - it does not, however, set the `.UpdateCommand`; the `.UpdateCommand` is specifically to *provide a custom update*